# Hbase reading freezes for a few records when reading with partial rowkey

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hbase, cloudera

I am reading data from HBase through spark. The code runs fine when reading the data using a prefix filter with a complete `rowkey` or using `GET`, but it freezes if I use a partial prefixed `rowkey`. The `rowkey` structure is `md5OfAkey_Akey_txDate_someKey`. I want to read all data matching “`Akeys`” from a data frame. The table has a **single column family , 50 column qualifiers and has around 200 million records**. So when I read using `md5OfAkey_Akey_txDate` the code gets stuck while if I construct the whole key it runs fine. But I do not want to pass the whole `rowkey` as I want to read all data for a particular account(`Akey`) and transaction date (`txDate`). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Performing a scan by partial rowkey (i.e. using PrefixFilter) is expected to be slower than direct `get`. Can you quantify "stuck" or does it never return?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I went ahead with the multirowrange filter in hbase and the code runs much faster than the prefix or the fuzzy filter. I am still not sure why the prefix filter was taking more than 10 minutes to get data for a single partial rowkey whereas the multirowrange filter brings the same data in seconds.